# Nestjs / Jestjs : Received: undefined, expected: 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs

The project use nestjs and the testing integrated with jestjs.

I try to test the function "getUserByID", which is on my "user.repository.js"

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';
import { UserModifyDto } from './dto/user-modify.dto';
import { ConflictException, InternalServerErrorException, NotFoundException, Logger, BadRequestException } from "@nestjs/common";

const mockUser = { id: 1, email: "email@email.com", password: "pass", salt: "XCVBxcf", isAdmin: false, isActive: true, activated: true };

const mockUserRepository = () => ({
    modifyUser: jest.fn(),
    remove: jest.fn(),
    getUserById: jest.fn(),
});

describe('User service', () => {
    let userService;
    let userRepository;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                UserService,
                { provide: UserRepository, useFactory: mockUserRepository }
            ],
        }).compile();

        userService = await module.get<UserService>(UserService);
        userRepository = await module.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository);
    });

    describe('modifyUser', () => {
        it('modify email', async () => {
            userRepository.modifyUser.mockResolvedValue({ email: "newEmail@email.com" });
            expect(userRepository.modifyUser).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

            const myModifyUser: UserModifyDto = { email: "newEmail@email.com", password: "pass", oldPassword: "pass", isActive: true, activated: true };

            const result = await userService.modifyUser(mockUser, myModifyUser);
            expect(userRepository.modifyUser).toHaveBeenCalled();

            expect(result.email).toEqual(myModifyUser.email);
        });

        it('modify password', async () => {
            userRepository.modifyUser.mockResolvedValue({ password: "newpass" });
            expect(userRepository.modifyUser).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

            const myModifyUser: UserModifyDto = { email: "email@email.com", password: "newpass", oldPassword: "pass", isActive: true, activated: true };

            const result = await userService.modifyUser(mockUser, myModifyUser);
            expect(userRepository.modifyUser).toHaveBeenCalled();

            expect(result.password).toEqual(myModifyUser.password);
        });

        it('modify active', async () => {
            userRepository.modifyUser.mockResolvedValue({ isActive: false });
            expect(userRepository.modifyUser).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

            const myModifyUser: UserModifyDto = { email: "email@email.com", password: "pass", oldPassword: "pass", isActive: false, activated: true };

            const result = await userService.modifyUser(mockUser, myModifyUser);
            expect(userRepository.modifyUser).toHaveBeenCalled();

            expect(result.isActive).toEqual(myModifyUser.isActive);
        });

        it('modify activated', async () => {
            userRepository.modifyUser.mockResolvedValue({ activated: false });
            expect(userRepository.modifyUser).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

            const myModifyUser: UserModifyDto = { email: "email@email.com", password: "pass", oldPassword: "pass", isActive: true, activated: false };

            const result = await userService.modifyUser(mockUser, myModifyUser);
            expect(userRepository.modifyUser).toHaveBeenCalled();

            expect(result.activated).toEqual(myModifyUser.activated);
        });

        it('modify but wrong old password', async () => {
            userRepository.modifyUser.mockImplementation(() => {
                throw new BadRequestException;
            });
        });

        it('modify but save impossible', async () => {
            userRepository.modifyUser.mockImplementation(() => {
                throw new InternalServerErrorException;
            });
        });
    });

    describe('getUserById', () => {
        it ('get a user', async () => {
            //userRepository.findOne.mockResolvedValue(mockUser.id);
            userRepository.getUserById.mockResolvedValue(mockUser.id);
            const result = await userRepository.getUserById(mockUser.id);
            expect(result.id).toEqual(mockUser.id);

        })
    })

    describe('Delete User', () => {
        it('Delete user without error', async () => {
            userRepository.remove.mockResolvedValue({ affected: 1});
            expect(userRepository.remove).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
            await userService.deleteUser(mockUser);
            expect(userRepository.remove).toHaveBeenCalledWith({mockUser})
        })
    })
});
```

setup of my testing file :

```
const mockUser = { id: 1, email: "email@email.com", password: "pass", salt: "XCVBxcf", isAdmin: false, isActive: true, activated: true };

const mockUserRepository = () => ({
    modifyUser: jest.fn(),
    remove: jest.fn(),
    getUserById: jest.fn(),
});

describe('User service', () => {
    let userService;
    let userRepository;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                UserService,
                { provide: UserRepository, useFactory: mockUserRepository }
            ],
        }).compile();

        userService = await module.get<UserService>(UserService);
        userRepository = await module.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository);
    });
```

and this is my test :

```
describe('getUserById', () => {
        it ('get a user', async () => {
            const mockUserForGet = {id : 1, email: "mock@email.com"};
            userRepository.getUserById.mockResolvedValue(mockUserForGet.id);
            const result = await userRepository.getUserById(mockUserForGet.id);

            expect(result.id).toEqual(mockUserForGet.id);

        })
    })
```

So my problem is the following, when i run the test, i've got the following result :

> expect(received).toEqual(expected)
>
> Expected: 1
>   Received: undefined

I don't know why. The function don't throw and the function is mock is the beginning of my testing file.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try `const found = await this.findOne({ id });`

Comment: @zishone Nothing change :/

Comment: Can you show how you setup the test? the `beforeEach` that has your `Test.createTestingModule` in it?

Comment: what code does function `this.findOne` contain and what would be output of `console.log(result)` in test?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Done ;)

Comment: @Yevhenii findOne -> function by nestjs
and my console return the user

Comment: Do you have any other tests in this file? Is it this test specifically that is failing? Can you provide a link to your code if not? I can't see anything inherently wrong with the test in a sense of funcitonality

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I have other tests, and they're working as expected.
Sorry I can't provide the source code :/ Tell me what you think you need as extra info

Comment: Can you show the full test file? Also, jsut as a heads up, this isn't really a useful test to begin with. There's a chance that another test is overriding the return and giving a false failure

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. You're mocking the return value as `mockUserForGet.id` which is a single value, not an object,. Then you are checking that `result` (a primitive) `.id` (undefined) is equal to `mockUserForGet` (an object) `.id` (a primitive), which makes sense that `expect(undefined).toEqual(primitive)` returns false and fails the test.

I do want to point out that this test doesn't do anything useful. You are mocking a function's return, calling that function, and asserting that the mock return is what you told the mock to be. It's like you're testing the jest library and not your actual code.